# Setting maxrequest length of fineuploader asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using fineuploader to upload file within my ASP.net MVC project.

However, I am having some trouble uploading large files.

My upload controller is also contained within an Area called 'Documents'.

I have included the following code within my root web.config file.

```
<location path="~/Documents/Upload/UploadFile">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
  <!--by default set to 100 MB-->
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="104857600" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

However, this does not seem to have any impact on the maxrequestlength and I cannot upload large files as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with your executionTimeout property, which may be less and timing out . As you need more time to upload the file of httpruntime section. By default it is 110 seconds , check here : http://forums.asp.net/t/1040377.aspx